# Solving Harmonic Numbers Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am entirely lost with proving harmonic numbers. I'm not sure what it is, but it is not good. The only thing I can do is the basis step.

$$H_{2^k}\leq k+1,\forall k\geq 0$$

I am actually a little confused with the basis step for this one though, for when k=1 it is ture, but not for k=2.

I'm not looking for an answer, but perhaps just the first two lines or so in the Inductive step with a small explanation if you don't mind.

Edit: As you can see in the last question I posted of this, I did not get an answer...

Comment: You asked this already: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576604/proving-harmonic-statement-with-induction

Comment: I did not get an answer...

Comment: Actually he asked how to prove $H_{2^k} \ge k+1$.  It was pointed out that it is not true.

Comment: Ya, its just a tad odd since it is worth so much..yes this is for an assignment, but I was terribly lost

Comment: how can the answer simply be...not true?

Comment: Well consider $k=1$.  $H_{2^1} = \frac32$ which is definitely not bigger than or equal to $1+1$.  So the statement you want to prove is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the extra terms you need to go from $H_{2^k}$ to $H_{2^{k+1}}$.  Notice that when you write it out, there are $2^k$ terms added together, and each of them is less that $\frac1{2^k}$.

Comment: well perhaps if we changed that sign to if k+1 is less than pr equal to. How would I prove it then?

Comment: I just told you in my answer.